# determining HTTP version using raw sockets in C

Tags: c++, sockets, http

I am trying to create raw sockets in C/C++, then create a request message and then send that message to a target server. If the port I specify happens to be `80` I want to send a HTTP request to determine the HTTP version that the target server is using. For e.g I send `GET HTTP/1.0` to `www.google.com`.

For some servers it returns `HTTP/1.1 400` bad request. While in some cases it responds with an XML message. I know the `GET` command is wrong since I am not specifying any object to actually `GET`. So is there a generic way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
HEAD / HTTP/1.0\r\n
\r\n
```

Or:

```
GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n
\r\n
```

The first line of the servers response should contain the HTTP version. Note that some servers will return `400 Bad Request` if the `Host: <hostname>` is omitted from the header (which is not required in 1.0, but in 1.1). I would do:

Try:

```
HEAD / HTTP/1.0\r\n
Host: <hostname>\r\n
\r\n
```

Or:

```
GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n
Host: <hostname>\r\n
\r\n
```

If you don't require the message body, you should use `HEAD` as it will require less data to receive.

Comment: Note, I don't think the `\r` characters are required; the HTTP specification allows them, but is OK with `\n` alone.

Answer (score 1):

```
GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n
Host: www.google.com\r\n
\r\n
```

This is a basic HTTP request. Alternatively, you can use `HEAD` instead of `GET`, sinse you only want the headers, but some basic servers don't recognize `HEAD` as a valid method.

Not every server will support HTTP/1.0, they will most likely ignore this and answer as HTTP/1.1, others will just ape the version in your request and not really mean it.

It can be frustrating to try to determine the HTTP version in a random server. Perhaps you should instead use 1.1 in the request and see if the server answers with 1.0, I believe it may be the safest way to know if the server is at least giving a damn.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to progressively try each version of HTTP. For example, if I query `google.com` with HTTP 1.0, it will respond with HTTP 1.0:

```
$ printf "HEAD / HTTP/1.0\nHost: google.com\n\n" | nc google.com 80
HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.google.com/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Tue, 26 Nov 2013 19:44:42 GMT
Expires: Thu, 26 Dec 2013 19:44:42 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=2592000
Server: gws
Content-Length: 219
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic
```

If I query it with HTTP 1.1, it will respond with HTTP 1.1:

```
$ printf "HEAD / HTTP/1.1\nHost: google.com\n\n" | nc google.com 80
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.google.com/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Tue, 26 Nov 2013 19:44:47 GMT
Expires: Thu, 26 Dec 2013 19:44:47 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=2592000
Server: gws
Content-Length: 219
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic
```